# what exactly happens when a user performs a http input on a website

Tags: http

I was wondering what exactly is happening when a user performs a http input, such as a number or word, on a website, which shall be handled by for instance a django backend. The backend part is understood, but what excatly happens on the frontend, so that the backend receives the input.

I get the overall mechanism(which is describted on many websites), but I was looking for a real insight, a deep dive on what happens exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly"? The browser gathers all data for the request and sends it to the server. Do you seek for an explanation about how the browser collects the data, how it transforms it to a network request, how that request itself works, ...?

Comment: i am looking for an explanation on every step which is necessary, so that the input is processed.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please explain how your problem is related to programming itself - do you want to resolve any **specific** problem?

Comment: it is not a specific problem, i like to understand the whole chain of actions. Maybe not suited for stackoverflow?